# Using Swift static library in all Swift project, builds & runs OK, editor thinks "no such module"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have read thru most of the questions related to Swift and static libraries here. This question is not a duplicate because:

- I am using/have built a Swift static library. This feature did not exist until Xcode 9, which was released 19 Sep 2017.
- I am using the Swift static library in an all Swift project. So many questions and answers start from the basis of dealing with ".h" header files, module maps, and/or interoperating with Objective-C.
- I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10 which became available 30 days ago. The pace of change in the language and the tooling invalidates so many old approaches.
- I actually have the build working. It is the editor which mistakenly reports an error.

I have the following code in a static lib:

```
public extension String {
    public func clever() -> String {
        return self + "_clever"
    }
}

public class TestMe {
    let word:String
    public init(word:String) {
        self.word = word
    }
    public func log() {
        print("TestMe.word = \(word)")
    }
}
```

I did Product > Archive of the static lib and looked at the logs to find the output.

I have a single-page app, with the only code different from the template being this:

```
import UIKit
import StaticLib

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let t = TestMe(word:"banana")
    let s = "bob"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let c = s.clever()
        print("c = \(c)")
        t.log()
    }
}
```

This is the folder structure of where I copied in the .a file and the .swiftmodule folder to the app.

```
2018-10-12T08:43:50 ~/Documents/Code/JustApp
‹master* M› » ls -lR Libs
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 jeff  staff  170 Oct 12 07:43 StaticLib

Libs/StaticLib:
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff    136 Oct 12 07:43 StaticLib.swiftmodule
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  29216 Oct 12 07:25 libStaticLib.a

Libs/StaticLib/StaticLib.swiftmodule:
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff    360 Oct 12 07:25 arm64.swiftdoc
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  15068 Oct 12 07:25 arm64.swiftmodule
```

It builds OK, and runs. Here is the console output.

```
c = bob_clever
TestMe.word = banana
```

But then here is what it looks like in the editor.

[image: sample code with editor error]

Here are the various PATH settings I updated.

[image]

This updates:

- FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS
- LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS
- FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS

An experienced person might tell me that I'm missing the header file and module map. But this app and lib is all Swift. I do not need a header file or module map. That is what the arm64.swiftmodule file does.

That person might continue and say, "Use them anyway because that might fix the editor problem." I tried that, and it made problem worse.

I created this module map:

```
module StaticLib {
    header "StaticLib-Swift.h"
    export *
}
```

I used the `StaticLib-Swift.h` and generated by Xcode during the Product > Archive step.

And this is what I get.

[image]

But again, the build still succeeds and the app runs just fine!

Comment: have you had any further success on this?

Comment: I was having this same exact issue last week and it went away after I restarted my computer for an unrelated reason.  I haven't been able to get the error to come back like this where it compiled fine, but still showed errors, but maybe by now you have already restarted?

Comment: @jacobbullock LOL! I will try that. I never thought of simply rebooting.

Comment: add related link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946503/trying-to-import-and-use-swift-static-library-results-in-no-such-module-error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my project by setting the:

`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO;`

flag in the build settings of the static library that isn't linking.

If it worked with "Generic iOS Devices" and not other targets, that was the first thing that came to mind.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you don't need the header file or module map.

Under "Swift Compiler - Search Paths" > "Import Paths" add the path to the .swiftmodule folder.