# Trying to import and use Swift static library results in no such module error

Tags: swift, static

I created a Swift static library called libShapeNodeDeformer.

I then copied the generated libShapeNodeDeformer.a,x86_64-apple-macos.swiftdoc, and x86_64-apple-macos.swiftmodule to a project folder that I want to use the library in and added them to that project.

I verified that the .a was listed under Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content.

I added the path to these 3 files to the Library search paths.

Next when I add the line import libShapeNodeDeformer in any of my source files I get an error "no such module".

I'm doing essentially everything that this post shows: https://railsware.com/blog/creation-of-pure-swift-module/

I also tried renaming x86_64-apple-macos.swiftmodule and x86_64-apple-macos.swiftdoc to libShapeNodeDeformer.swiftmodule and libShapeNodeDeformer.swiftdoc

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a module.modulemap file with the following content:
module libShapeNodeDeformer {
link "ShapeNodeDeformer"
export *
}